# BOINC: Is there an easy example how to code a programm for it and how to implement it into their client/server system?

Tags: methods, distributed-computing, numeric, boinc

I did a numeric method as my diploma thesis and coded it in java. It needs a lot of computational time when adequately executed. So I looked for an alternative and found BOINC. Unfortunately I didn't have time for doing my method in BOINC, because I'm an Aerospace student and not a programmer and I decided to keep my priority on my java program. Now it's finished an I still would like to port this to BOINC environment.

Unfortunately I'm learning in re-doing examples and I couldn't find any, neither on the official site http://boinc.berkeley.edu nor in the internet.
So do you know a good and easy example or do you have any experience in BOINC and would like to start a new platform for such a boinc project?

I'm realistic about my method, that it wouldn't run 24/7, because there aren't as many work units as for seti or folding projects. So I would like to have a platform for more than just my project so that another platform project can be worked on, when one part of the project does not have any work units at that moment.

But to start this, I would keep it simple and just want to know how to code it and use it in the client and server system. It doesn't matter what the example projects will work on, as long as it is simple enough, that I can understand it and extending it for my method.

Thank you in advance, Andreas! :)

PS: I know that BOINC supports JAVA as a programming language, and my method is coded in JAVA.

Comment: Where did you see that BOINC supports Java?

Comment: Hi Nicolas,
http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/JavaApps
As far as I understand this, you can use the working code in BOINC's sandbox.
I don't mean that the complete client can be done in that, just the computational part for the work units.

But I can be wrong! :)

But never the less, would you be interested in helping?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [JavaApps](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/JavaApps) is just an idea; I don't know if anyone actually *tried* it in a real BOINC project. And it's Windows-only. And it seems to be a bit of a pain to redistribute the entire JRE as part of the BOINC application (both technically and legally).

Also, I generally dislike using that kind of “wrapper” where the science app (using the BOINC API) starts another process that then does the real computation. It's usually unreliable. There are lots of things that could go wrong with the wrapper, especially related to controlling the child process (eg. if something kills the wrapper, the child process has to quit too).

However, I just found something pretty interesting that may let me do a better Java wrapper for BOINC... Stay tuned! (but don't hold your breath either; it's the holidays!)

---

Meanwhile, I suggest you start by reading [BOINC wiki](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/ProjectMain) and setting up a server with a “hello world” application; and if you have any trouble, ask a specific question about your trouble either [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or in the [boinc_projects mailing list](http://lists.ssl.berkeley.edu/mailman/listinfo/boinc_projects).

(Of course, payin’ me to install the server for you is also an option ;) but I can't guarantee anything; not even my mere availability at this time of the year)

Comment: Hi Nicolas and thank you so far (+1)

"[...] However, I just found something pretty interesting that may let me do a better Java wrapper for BOINC... Stay tuned! (but don't hold your breath either; it's the holidays!)"

Don't worry, I don't expext anything byadeadline. Hollidays are important for me, so I don't urge anyone to work during these days :D.

As usual payment isn't the first option, because it just my private wish to do that right now (okay, a friend of mine would also like to participate), so Idon't have any fundings.
I just wantto try this and extend it, if it will work.

Comment: ... and could you please tell me where to find the stuff I need for the "hello world" app? I don't get their order to start as a newbie.